# Shown router IP doesn't work

Tags: macos, router, ip

I've been trying to get a router's IP address to configure it. It's a [D-Link DIR-615](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/home-solutions/connect/routers/dir-615-wireless-n-300-router) router. I've seen a few answers on how to get the router's IP address, though none of them works, it shows the router's address but I can't reach its page (and I'm sure it's different from what's shown!).

[image: Router IP Address According to macOS Network Settings]

So, how do I get to the actual working IP address of my router?

Comment: What are you using to access the router?  Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: You could try using `http://dlinkrouter` unless it was changed

Comment: Most of the time a home router also serves as default gateway. Which is shown here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YIz19.png  That is the IP you want.

Comment: Do have a wireless AP between the router and the device connected like in you screenshot ?

Comment: @Blerg I've tried accessing the router via Wifi. Also, there is a MikroTik RB951Ui connected to this router via ethernet. I think maybe MikroTik router is 'changing' the router's IP, is it possible?

Comment: @pun this didn't work. It opens a website which is showing ads.

Comment: @Hennes so you mean I can get the actual IP when connected via ethernet? Because in Wifi settings of the router, there is no 'Default Gateway'.

Comment: @Overmind There is a MikroTik RB951Ui which is also connected to this router via ethernet, sorry I'm confused!

Comment: Since you mention something between you and your router, how is it connected to your router?  Does it have an IP address as well?  Does it have a WAN IP address?

Comment: Make a simple schematic of how the devices are connected. Example: WAN-->DLINK-->MikroTik-->YourDevice. Make sure to check in what ports what cables go.

Comment: Let me explain, on D-Link router: one cable goes to a VoIP Phone, one cable goes to a PC (for CCTV), one cable goes to power source (via a swtich, if I'm telling the right name for it!), and another cable goes to the MikroTik router. / on MikroTik router: two cables go to NVR devices, one cable goes to a VoIP Phone, one cable goes to a power source (via the same swtich where D-Link router is connected), and clearly one cable has been used to connect it to the D-Link router. Hope I explained it correctly. :) I can draw the schematic if needed.

Comment: @Blerg both routers have IP addresses, actually I can connect to both routers on Wifi.

Comment: If you can connect to your router, then you should be able to connect to its web interface.  After connecting to the D-Link, look at your gateway or router in the network window.  Then use your web browser to connect to that IP address.  You may need to add `http://` or `https://` before the IP address to get there.  Some browsers attempt to do a search for you by default instead of trying to use the address as an address first.

Comment: @Blerg tried everything, on different browsers. Still no luck!

Answer (score 2):

[According to this site](http://m.setuprouter.com/router/dlink/dir-615/login.htm), your router’s login page is at `192.168.0.1` and the username is `admin` and the password is simply blank.

Comment: The default settings of the router was changed, so these default values don't work.

Comment: @ParsiKade Then reset the router ...

Comment: @DavidPostill well that's not an option!

Answer (score 0):

There are two routers involved in your setup and it is not clear which is doing what, and which is which. So let's try and figure this out first, and maybe even more.

Download and install [nmap](https://nmap.org/download.html) wich is a network security scanner. It has GUI program which is called Zenmap. Run it and in the target type `192.168.0.1`, for profile choose Intense scan. The tool will take some time to complete. After it finishes it will show you comprehensive data for the router, including any open ports on it. This is important since the default port (80) on which the router is serving it's configuration may be changed. You can post the output here or you can try and if the tool has found something like this (for example):

```
8081/tcp  open  http
```

then you can try to open the web interface on that port, by typing this into your browser address bar:

```
http://192.168.0.1:8081
```

If that succeeds - then you made it. If not:

In the output of nmap you will see the mac address behind the ip of `192.168.0.1`. It should be something like:

MAC Address: `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`, where XX is combination of numbers and/or letter. Copy that address and paste it and this tool:

```
https://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html
```

It will tell you whether behind the ip of `192.168.0.1` is the D-Link or Mikrotik router and we will take it from there, since there are major differences in those two routers.

Comment: I installed nmap on Mac (though when installed it was named 'Zenmap', but seems to be the same thing). Here's the result: 53/tcp   open  domain         MikroTik RouterOS named or OpenDNS Updater
80/tcp   open  http?
2000/tcp open  bandwidth-test MikroTik bandwidth-test server
8291/tcp open  unknown     //     I couldn't access web interface (tried :8291 and even :80!). I was connected to the D-Link router, not MikroTik.

Comment: I also tried to copy the MAC Address in the link you provided, though what I got was: ":5E:0C Routerboard.com".

Comment: In the past, only D-Link router had internet access, but then it was somehow linked to the MikroTik router and now both have internet access (two different Wifi networks).

Comment: Ok, so from the looks of it, you got the mikrotik behind the ip of 192.168.0.1. Is it possible someone else to be able to configure your devices? Such changes doesn't happen by itself. There are good news in this situation: it looks like port 8291 is open on your mikrotik router, which is the winbox configuration interface. You can [download winbox](http://www.mikrotik.com/download) and try to connect to this port by typing the router ip in connect to field.

Comment: yes someone else has configured the device. I actually have access to winbox configuration interface. You mean I can also access the D-Link router via winbox?

Comment: also, if you're saying that 192.168.0.1:8291 should navigate me to MikroTik web config interface, that's not the case. / Sorry, i'm not able to mention you, don't know why. :)

Comment: Port 8291 is not web interface is just winbox :) If you could login into winbox then go to IP->Arp you will see the ip/mac addresses for all devices. Then you can copy each mac address into [wireshak oui lookup tool](https://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html) and identify the DLink router.

Comment: I logged on to winbox and opened ARP settings, there I could see 9 IP addresses. So I copied each one of them to Wireshark oui lookup tool, one result was: 00:24:01 D-Link Corporation and the IP address associated with it was 192.168.0.5. Though when I try to access router using this IP, I only get a white 'blank' screen.